# SharePoint uploads documents to subfolders

Tags: 2013, document-library, publishing-page

On a publishing page in DEV, when editing HTML field and I upload a document using the Upload button from Ribbon, and select Documents library as the destination list, the uploaded file gets uploaded to the root of the Documents library.

However, when users upload documents in PROD, SharePoint creates subfolder to the root of the Documents library, and upload the files inside that subfolder. Subfolder name is the file name of the publishing page.

Some random publishing pages in Pages library:

[image]

Some random subfolders that have been generated in Documents library:

[image]

Why is SharePoint creating this subfolder, and why it only occurs on some users? I have tried uploading with different browsers, with different users (having different permissions), but have been unable to reproduce in DEV. I haven't been able to find any reference to this functionality in SharePoint, so any pointers and thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: That's rare.I have not seen like this.No Event Receiver attached I guess?

Comment: No event receivers, pure SharePoint file upload via Ribbon Upload button when modifying HTML field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a document library is defined as "Site Assets Library" in library Advanced Settings, then SharePoint will upload items into subfolders in the designated Site Assets library.